# Strange output from using 'say'

Tags: perl

I need a second pair of eyes on this. I'm getting an extra newline whenever one of the conditionals (if or elsif) is true. I don't want that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = 'rr.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $filename;

while (<$fh>) {
  my ($last_name, $first_name, $country) = split /[,\|]/, $_;
  my $middle_name;
  $country =~ s/^\(//;
  $country =~ s/\)$//;
  say "Last Name: $last_name";
  say "First Name: $first_name";
  say "Country: $country";

  if ($first_name =~ /\w\s(\w+)/) {
     $middle_name = $1;
     say "Middle Name: $1";
  } elsif ($first_name =~ /\w\-(\w+)/) {
     $middle_name = $1;
     say "Middle Name: $1";
  }

}
```

The file looks like this:

```
Reid, Matt|(AUS)
Samper-Montana, Jordi|(ESP)
Krajonovic, Filip|(SRB)
Jones, Greg Luke|(AUS)
Burquier, Gregoire|(FRA)
Mandol, David|(ARG)
Daniel Llosa, Miguel Horpo|(DOM)
```

Whenever a middle name would get outputted it would be preceded by a newline. I don't know where that is coming from.
The same thing happens by using print and appending a newline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`say` adds a newline to the end of the output.  The country codes you read have a newline still attached since you didn't `chomp` the input line.  So, you get double-spaced output (from a newline after the country, rather than a newline before the middle name).

Fix: add `chomp;` before the `split` line.

Comment: Obviously. Rookie mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @user3046061 - making rookie mistakes is how one stops being a rookie :)